# Integration by parts and non-absolutely continuous distributions

Tags: integration, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $x\in [a,b]$ be a real random variable with distribution $H$ that is not absolutely continuous (w.r.t Lebesgue measure). 
I saw this in a paper:
$$
\int_a^b xH(dx) = b-\int_a^bH(x)dx.
$$
I get it is integration by parts but I am not sure why it should work. Is there some implicit assumption on $H$ at work here or does this always hold? 
Edit: I think there may be an implicit assumption that $H$ is a Borel measure.

Comment: dumb question: $H(dx)$ is referring like $dg(x)$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the left side. The value of the integral depends on whether one, none or both of the end points are included. If you assume that $H$ is continuous then the integral is well defined. Here is the general formula for integration by parts (I leave it to you to derive your result as a special case): let $F$ and $G$ be distribution functions on $\mathbb R$. Then $\int_{(-\infty , x]} F dG+\int_{(-\infty , x]} G dF =F(x)G(x)$. To prove this simply apply Fubini's Theorem to find $(F \times G) ((-\infty , x] \times (-\infty , x])=\int I_{(-\infty , x] \times (-\infty , x]} (u,v) d(F\times G)(u,v)$ in two ways (first integrating with respect to $F$, the with respect to $G$ and then the other way).